# MFPF V8 Operations Console user authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Hello I'm trying to setup a list of users to access the MFPF Operations Console using the different role. I changed the server.xml as follow but without positive result.

basicRegistry added group and users:

```
<group name="mfpdeployergroup"/>
  <member name="guest"/>
  <member name="demo"/>
</group>

<user name="guest" password="guest"/>
<user name="demo" password="demo"/>
```

Added for Administration service and Operations console applications the role mapping:

```
<security-role name="mfpdeployer">
    <group name="mfpdeployergroup"/>
</security-role>
```

Still receiving the error:

[12/2/16 17:36:11:368 CET] 000000fb .ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl A CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user demo while invoking mfpconsole on /index.html. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [mfpadmin, mfpmonitor, mfpoperator, mfpdeployer].

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear if you're trying to add a user in the devkit or in liberty or what...?

In the devkit I have edited the mfpserver\usr\servers\mfp\server.xml file.

1. In `<basicRegistry>` I've added: `<user name="idan" password="idan"/>`
2. In `<application id="mfpconsole" name="mfpconsole" location="mfp-admin-ui.war" type="war">`, under `<security-role name="mfpdeployer">` I've added: `<user name="idan"/>`.

I was then able to login using idan\idan.

Comment: Hi Idan, I'm on a liberty profile with MFPF installed on it. The user works also for me but not the group. Is the group working for you ?

Comment: I haven't tried groups. Don't know this liberty feature.

Comment: Here the links: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_wl_admin.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0 /com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_configuration_of_the_wl_admin.html#c_configuration_of_the_wl_admin Can you test it with a simple group es explained above in my link ?